# Можно ли менять свое решение, когда ответ уже принят?

Tags: обсуждение

Я иногда отвечаю на вопросы, которые уже приняты, и случается, что авторы меняют свое решение: принимают мой ответ.

**С одной стороны, это приятно, но с другой — огорчает,** потому что начинаешь себя неловко чувствовать. Первый автор получит минус пятнадцать баллов, ему будет неприятно, часть негативных эмоций достанется и мне.

**Поэтому я бы не стала так делать.** Лучше сразу не принимать первый ответ, подождать другие. Но если принял, но не надо менять свое решение.

Такие ситуации случаются, хотя и не часто. Но самое интересное — это когда **автор два раза менял свое мнение:** принял ответ, потом принял мой ответ, потом опять передумал и принял первый. И всё это не в один день, так что система показывала обоим отвечающим уменьшение репутации. Что руководило его действиями, остается только догадываться (вариантов для объяснения много, и не все характеризуют его с хорошей стороны).

**А как Вы относитесь к подобным случаям?** Конечно, исключительно с точки зрения этики поведения, так как запретить такие действия, очевидно, нельзя.

Comment: Просто некоторые не знают, что галочка может быть только одна, а потом, обнаружив это, заново отмечаю самый важный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Наверно, это нормальный процесс: мы можем изменить мнение — а вдруг новый ответ действительно лучше предыдущего?

Когда выбор между ответам меняется много раз за один день, вероятно, стоит просто лучше подумать и сделать единственный, но верный выбор.

Comment: Слово нормальный весьма относительно, в частности нормы поведения  меняются во времени, также они  устанавливаются для определенного общества. Эти нормы не являются обязательными, но они характеризуют это общество. И вот мне такой"нормальный процесс" не нравится, хотя это дело каждого участника.

Comment: Про слово "нормальный" я в одном романе прочитала забавный анекдот. Вот рассказ персонажа:  У меня был друг – отличный парень и не дурак, что достаточно редко бывает в одном человеке. И вот однажды он взял и сошёл с ума. Совершенно для всех неожиданно. Увезли его в психбольницу, и я, потрясённый, так сказать, случившимся, поехал к нему с визитом. Апельсины, сочувствие, любопытство. Спрашиваю его: «Как у тебя здесь соседи?» А он и говорит: "Вроде бы нормальные".

Comment: Aer, здравствуйте! Пытался задать вопрос здесь, на Мете, но система не пропускает (говорит, не соответствует правилам). Может, знаете, есть ли на сайте возможность делать неразрывный пробел, чтобы не было ситуаций, когда элементы таких сочетаний, как, например, ***и т. д.***, или инициалы и фамилия оказываются на разных строчках.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец здравствуйте! Задайте вопрос, просто после своей короткой формулировки допишите чего-нибудь еще (можно бессмысленного), чтобы система пропустила по объему. А затем после публикации удалите лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо! А так, навскидку, как думаете, есть здесь функция неразрывного пробела? Если бы была, то, наверное, уже давно бы ею пользовались и рекомендовали другим. Так что и вопрос такой задавать не стоит...

Answer (score 0):

Можно было бы баллы отнимать только если автор вопроса просто *отменил* выбор ответа, а не переключил выбор с одного ответа на другой - просто новый ответ лучше, а автор первого ни в чём не провинился. Или лучше дать автору вороса решать - отзывать баллы за ответ или не стоит, например, если он обнаружит, что ответ неправильный.

Но я бы позволил множественность принятых ответов.
Можно принятым после первого ответам давать половину баллов.